# Pre-requisite license of True DBGrid DLL compilation stops VSTS auto build

Tags: azure-devops, devops

we are using True DBGrid in our .NET project. This requires a first time registration while we perform build of the project. When we build from Visual Studio (v2015) it asks through a popup for the license key first time then performs the build. Next onwards it somehow understand this registration and perform build without asking again. This procedure works fine in on-prem Visual Studio.
But currently we are trying to move our solution to VSTS cloud. And this pre-requisite license of True DBGrid stops our build pipeline, since neither we can procedure the popup during auto-build nor we can let VSTS cloud server know about that license key. Can you advice how we can successfully let VSTS server know about the license of this 3rd party True DBGrid component?
I believe when we run it from on-prem Visual Studio the license successfully register the True DBGrid component into our local server. But this simply we can not do in VSTS cloud server. Can you please help us to solve this problem and adopt VSTS DevOps feature successfully? Thanks, Dimitry.

Comment: Got some reference over here - https://www.grapecity.com/en/forums/c1-studio/activation-on-visual-studi
Looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t ComponentOne products installed on Hosted agent and base on [componentone-licensing](https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/componentone-licensing) document, it needs administrative rights to call CILicenseActivation.exe tool to register license, so you can’t do it on Hosted build agent.

You can setup a private build agent and running as your account. [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows)